# JQuery UI Animation - Slide Divs and attached Divs smoothly

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a toolbox which expands when you click a bar. A different div (which was hidden) will then "slide" to the right coming out of the screen resulting in the toolbox being opened fully. When you click the bar again the toolbox will close.

**The problem is as follows:** The hidden div will (as aimed for) smoothly appear, and it slides to the right. The bar, which is next to that div, will just be "teleported" to the right, where the hidden div will end.

I'm sure this is very confusing for some of you all, so let me share you screenshots of my problem.

**Before Sliding:** http://prntscr.com/amrgl0 
**While Sliding:** http://prntscr.com/amrhy5 
**After Sliding:** http://prntscr.com/amrgyq

The "Before" and "After" are like it should, but while the div is sliding I want the div attached to it to go with it.

My HTML Structure:

```
<div id="toolboxWrap">
      <div id="toolboxRow"><span>></span></div>
      <div id="toolboxContent">
            <div id="toolboxTitle"><h2>Toolbox</h2></div>
      </div>
 </div>
```

My JQuery:

```
const arrowOpen = "&gt;";
const arrowClose = "&lt;";

$("#toolboxRow").click(function(event){
    $("#toolboxContent").toggle("slide");
    $("#toolboxRow").children().html($("#toolboxRow").children().html() == arrowOpen ? arrowClose : arrowOpen);

});
```

Please note that my ToolboxWrap has an **absolute** position.

I hope my question is properly asked, thanks for your time.

Comment: Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: It's difficult to help without a live example we can play with and debug.